# The goback function of WKWebView does not execute javascript code

Tags: wkwebview

In UIWebView, if i call the function goback, the previous page will be present and execute its js code and set title on navigation bar. However, this do not work in wkwebview, it seems that wkwebview cache something and the js code is not executed.

Comment: I found that the  javascript code in the onload function will be executed when click goback button in uiwebview, but this does not happen in wkwebview

Answer (score 2):

I think the `WKWebView` is actually the more correct behaviour regarding the `load` event.

I have found that the `pageshow` event is better suited for code that needs to run on navigation changes.

Something like this should work in the `WKWebView`:

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function(event) {
    // We were just shown again. Either initial load or due to
    // navigation.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and the webpage was't being reloaded (on iOS 9.2 or higher versions) because it was showing a cached one, when calling `goBack`.

'Fixed' that clearing the cache data before calling goBack on the `WKWebView`. I still don't know if it is an iOS bug or Apple just decided to change the default behaviour from iOS 9.2.

In Objective-C would be something like this:

```
- (void)goBack {

    [self cleanCacheWithCompletionHandler:^{
       [super goBack];
    }];
}

- (void)cleanCacheWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {

    if ([WKWebsiteDataStore class]) {

        NSSet *websiteDataTypes = [NSSet setWithArray:@[ WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache,
                                                         WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache]];
        NSDate *dateFrom = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
        [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:websiteDataTypes modifiedSince:dateFrom completionHandler:completionHandler];
    } else {

        completionHandler();
    }
}
```

Note that I subclassed `WKWebView` in the sample code and that you have to check the availability of `WKWebsiteDataStore` as it is new to iOS 9.